# Hide a whole div with CSS with part of it is empty

Tags: css, hide

Is there a way to hide a whole div if part of it is empty? For example if "dd" is empty as shown below can I hide the whole class "test" so the keyword Restrictions does not show either. I tried .test dd:empty { display: none;  } but this does not work. thanks!

```html
  <div class="test"><dt>Restrictions:</dt>
  <dd></dd></div>
```

Comment: CSS alone can't do that. Either, you need a javascript to retrieve empty elements and hide their parents, or your CMS applies special CSS classes if there's no content.

Comment: @Paul, please post your response as an answer! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's any easy way to do what you're talking about with just CSS. Better to test it server-side if you can. But if you can't here's some JS that will do the job.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
// handles multiple dt/dd pairs per div and hides them each conditionally
function hideIfEmpty() {

    // get all the elements with class test
    var els = document.getElementsByTagName('dl');
    // for every 'test' div we find, go through and hide the appropriate elements
    Array.prototype.map.call(els, function(el) {
        var children = el.childNodes;
        var ddEmpty = false;
        for(var i = children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if(children[i].tagName === 'DD' && !children[i].innerHTML.trim()) {
                ddEmpty = true;
            } else if(children[i].tagName === 'DT') {
                if(ddEmpty) {
                    children[i].style.display = 'none';
                }
                // reset the flag
                ddEmpty = false;
            }
        }
    });

}

window.addEventListener('load', hideIfEmpty);
</script>

<div class="test">
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <dl>
        <dt>Restrictions:</dt>
        <dd></dd>
        <dt>Other Restrictions:</dt>
        <dd>Since I have content, I won't be hidden.</dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

Just a fair warning: the code uses some functions that may not exist in older IE, such as `Array.prototype.map`, `String.prototype.trim`, and `addEventListener`. There are polyfills available for these and you could also write your own pretty easily (or just do it with a for loop instead).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, AmadeusDrZaius. This is very helpful!
I have an additional element in my code - dl. See below. How can I add this to the JS code? 


<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->

<!-- language: lang-html -->

<div class="test">
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<dl>
    <dt>Restrictions:</dt>
    <dd></dd>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <dt>Other Restrictions:</dt>
    <dd>Since I have content, I won't be hidden.</dd>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </dl>
</div>


<!-- end snippet -->

Comment: Ah, well, in the above code, it's traversing all the children of the `.test` div. So currently, it would check the elements: `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` and `<dl>...</dl>`. You need to make it check the children of the `<dl>`, so you have to go one level down further by doing children of children. However, if you want this behavior on *all* of your `dl`'s, then you can just iterate over `document.getElementsByTagName('dl')` instead of `document.getElementsByClassName('test')`. I've updated the code to reflect this change.

Comment: Thanks AmadeusDrZaius! That worked great! I appreciate your help!

Comment: By the way, is it possible to set display order using CSS. For example the code in our system is added as the following. But the "time" appears first on the front end, second "location" and third "duration". Is it possible to set a fixed display order as follows: "duration", "time" and "location". 

    <dl>
      <dt>duration</dt>
      <dd>duration</dd>
      <dt>time</dt>
      <dd>time</dd>
      <dt>location</dt>
      <dd>location</dd>
    </dl>

Comment: @Parlanchina Of course you can set the order of elements in CSS by using relative positioning, but what you *can't* do (as far as I know) is conditionally show elements based on the content of their relative elements. This requires either something server-side (like PHP) or JS.

Answer (score 0):

You could update your CSS to be

```
.test{ 
display: none; 
color: transparent;
}
```

This would make the text transparent too, but display:none should hide it anyway.

---

To make the div with the id test ONLY show when the dd tag is EMPTY, and you can use jQuery, try the following JavaScript along with the CSS:

```
if($("dd").html().length ==0)
{show();
}
```

**Note: this solution requires jQuery, which is a JavaScript library.**

Comment: Thanks but this hides the .test class permanently. I want to hide it only in case dd is empty and display it when there is text in dd.

Comment: I think, OP wants to make it disappear ONLY IF `dd` is empty.

Comment: @Parlanchina Is dd a javascript variable? Or a div?

Comment: -1 for "You also need jquery". Everything that jquery does can be done with pure JS. It's a nice library, but your comment is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

CSS alone can't do that. Either, you need a javascript to retrieve empty elements and hide their parents, or your CMS applies special CSS classes if there's no content.

*Put as an answer as requested by @Barett.*